# mysql permissions in RHEL 6

Tags: mysql

i installed mysql server and mysql work bench in RHEL 6.i want to give access to all others system(which are windows xp) in my LAN so that they can access mysql database via mysql querybrowser.

Answer (score 0):

try this command on mysql prompt:

> mysql> Grant All privileges to "**Database name**".* at "**Username**"@"**IP or
>   DNS name of system**" identified by "passsword to be set for access"

You need to replace the letters in bold with your values.